# How to see the edges/vertex point of Boolean without having to apply the modifier?

Tags: modifiers, edges

I have applied the Boolean modifier to create a hole and would like to select the edge of that hole to extrude it out. But then I cannot see the edge or vertex points to do that unless I apply the boolean modifier (which I don't want to apply). Is there any way to make the edge visible without having to apply the modifier? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello, no you won't be able to see the edges, vertices or faces unless you apply the boolean, as long as it is not applied, these vertices don't exist yet. I know there is the project of doing a modifier that will allow to manipulate vertices of non-applied modifiers but it doesn't exist yet

Comment: The big advantage of leaving the modifier on the object is being able to edit the cutter object to change the shape of the hole.  You can disable visibility on the cutter or delete the faces leaving edges.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, too, using Knife Project with **Cut through** box checked. If you don't like the result you plain undo it. One thing to observe: having used this tool you need to bridge edge loops.